# Not able to display pdf in browser without toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to display pdf in browser

```
<embed src="D:\Books\Git\Scott.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0&statusbar=0&navpanes=0" width="500" height="500">
```

I want only simple pdf in browser to display without giving any option like download, print to the user. This code is not working for me. Please help

Comment: Why bother disabling the download? The user can download the pdf easily even if there is no button.

Comment: @lego Thanks for quick response. Actually according to requirement we just need to diplay simple pdf to user without options. We give a print button below pdf to print the document.